# Empty span causes weird margin / padding

Tags: margin, html, css

When I place a fixed size display-block `<span>` element inside a `<div>` it causes a weird margin or padding (I don't know) at the bottom of the `<div>`. When there is text inside the `<span>` element, everything is fine. What's the reason for this? How can I fix it? I tested on Firfox and Chrome.

[Weird space http://picster.at/img/0/9/6/0968c75ddf29ad07cb71eee2cff472a9.png](http://picster.at/img/0/9/6/0968c75ddf29ad07cb71eee2cff472a9.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .outer {
        background: grey;
        padding: 4px;
    }
    .inner {
        display: inline-block;
        background: cyan;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
    }
    -->
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <span class="inner">Foo</span>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="outer">
        <span class="inner"></span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update:**

Floating would be an alternative to display-block elements. Perfectly valid, however I would like to understand what's wrong with display-block in this example. Also, it doesn't look like a white-space problem to me, as this would only affect margin to the left/right (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: what exactly is the issue? this looks like expected output to me?

Comment: @Tanner, the second grey box is bigger (*taller*) than the first one

Comment: The bottom padding of the `<div>` increased from 4px to 9px. Or the bottom margin of the `<span>` increased from 0px to 5px. Firefox' boxmodel inspector tells me, nothing has changed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using `inline-block;`, this is the best example of how `inline-block` is different from `floats`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TSugb/)

```
.outer {
    background: grey;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    float: left;
    background: cyan;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

`inline-block` leaves whitespace of 4px margin.

[**More Info**](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Comment: I know that white-space affects the rendering of inline block elements, but that seems not to be the problem in this case. Also, this would add 4px to the side, not 5px to the bottom. Can you explain the overflow hidden thing?

Comment: @Jack I've floated elements to left, so am using `overflow: hidden;` for clearing floats

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the float.

Comment: I feel like this is the cleanest fix, so I accept this answer. I'd still appreciate if someone could explain what goes wrong with inline-block though :)

Comment: @Jack You need to know the difference between floats and inline-block, some people use `inline-block` instead of floats, but in reality they have some differences, as `inline-block;` is still in element flow, where if you use floats, it is like a complete different positioning :)

Comment: But how does that make the outer box taller?

Comment: It results in Margin between inner and outer element, read few articles

Comment: I did. None of them mentioned additional margins when an inline-block element has no content. And with content, it has no additional margins. Neither Firefox nor Chrome show those margins in their inspectors.

Answer (score 4):

This hack works great for me.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x495s/)

```
.inner:after{
        content: '\00a0';
}
```

Comment: Kind of adds fake content to div i.e. `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

inline-block is messing it up

If your intention of setting it as inline-block was to set a row of .inner's, set change the inner to block, and float left.

Then use a div with clear: both to fix the issue that normally the floating causes.

Here's your code modified:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .outer {
        background: grey;
        padding: 4px;
    }
    .inner {
        display: block;
        background: cyan;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }
    .clear{
        clear:both;
    }
    -->
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <span class="inner">Foo</span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="outer">
        <span class="inner"></span>
        <span class="inner"></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by setting the "line-height" of the outer element to 0. This solves pretty much every case.

Don't forget to make sure the inner element doesn't inherit that though, to do this you can just set it to "line-height:initial".

```
.outer {
        background: grey;
        padding: 4px;
        line-height:0;
    }
    .inner {
        display: inline-block;
        background: cyan;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        line-height:initial;
    }
```